# How to setup basic auth for Prometheus deployed on K8s cluster using yamls?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

How to setup basic auth for Prometheus deployed on K8s cluster using yamls??

I was able to achieve this easily when Prometheus was deployed on a host locally using tar file. But when it is deployed as a pod in K8s cluster, tried almost everything on the internet but no luck.

Any kind of help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why would [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/basic-auth/) work only in a vm and not container, but if it truly not work than you can use webserver to hide your web interface behind it and setup authentication on it.